# OpenCV Error "Sizes of input arguments do not match" in my SIFT algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

 /// Global Variables
 int DELAY_CAPTION = 1500;
 int DELAY_BLUR = 100;
 int MAX_KERNEL_LENGTH = 31;

Mat src; Mat   dst_inv,dst,dest[12],dog[8],grad_x,grad_x_2,grad_x_2_1,temp,p1,p2,x_max,hess[5];
char window_name[] = "Smoothing Demo";

/// Function headers
int display_caption(const char* caption);
int display_dst(int delay);
double k,v;
int width,height,m = 0,m1 = 0,width2,height2;
int sum1,r = 10,g = 0,c = 0;
/**
 * function main
 */
int main(void)
{
namedWindow(window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
ofstream outputfile;
outputfile.open("data4.txt");

/// Load the source image
src = imread("C:/Users/Adithyaanirudhha/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/ConsoleApplication2/pa.jpg", 1);

if (display_caption("Original Image") != 0) { return 0; }

dst = src.clone();
width = src.size().width;
height = src.size().height;
Size size(height,width);
if (display_dst(DELAY_CAPTION) != 0) { return 0; }
cvtColor(src, src, CV_RGB2GRAY);
/// Applying Gaussian blur


//for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
//{
//resize(src, src, size / 2);
k = 2 ^ (1 / 2);
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
//if (display_caption("Gaussian Blur") != 0) { return 0; }
GaussianBlur(src, dst, Size(), 1.6*k, 1.6*k);
if (display_dst(DELAY_BLUR*10) != 0) { return 0; }
k = k * k;
dst.copyTo(dest[m]);
//dest[m] = dst;
m++;
}
//}

Mat dog_inv;
for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
{
    if(m1!=3 || m1 != 6 || m1 != 9)
    subtract(dest[m1 + 1], dest[m1], dog[n],noArray(),-1);
}
imshow(window_name, dog[1]);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Sobel(dog[1], grad_x, CV_16S, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_x, grad_x);
    transpose(grad_x, temp);
    Sobel(dog[1], grad_x_2, CV_16S, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    Mat tmp;
    dog[1].convertTo(tmp, CV_32F);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_x_2, grad_x_2);
    c = invert(tmp,dog_inv, DECOMP_SVD);
    //imshow(window_name,src);
    Sobel(dog[1], grad_x_2_1, CV_16S, 2, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    convertScaleAbs(grad_x_2_1, grad_x_2_1);
    //imshow(window_name,src);
    //grad_x_2_1 = grad_x_2_1.inv(CV_32F);
    multiply(grad_x_2_1,grad_x,x_max, 1, 1);
    multiply(temp, x_max, p1, 1, 1);
    transpose(x_max,temp);
    multiply(temp, grad_x_2, p2, 1, 1);
    multiply(p2, x_max, p2, 1, 1);
    imshow(window_name, dog[1]);

    /*for (int y = 0; y < dog[i].rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < dog[i].cols; x++)
        {
            dog[i].at<Vec3b>(y, x) = (-1 * (p1.at<Vec3b>(y, x)) + 0.5*(p2.at<Vec3b>(y, x)) + dog[i].at<Vec3b>(y, x));
        }
    }*/
    //imshow(window_name, dog[1]);
    //imshow(window_name, src);
    /*  for (i = 0; i<2; i++)
    {
    v = determinant(dog[i]);
    }
    for (int h = 0; h < dog[1].rows; h++)
    {
    sum1 = dog[1].at<uchar>(h, h);
    }
    }
    if ((sum1 ^ 2) / v >((r + 1) ^ 2) / r)
    {
    hess[g] = dog[1];
    }
    */
    /// Wait until user press a key
    //display_caption("End: Press a key!");

        //imshow(window_name, dog[1]);
        //waitKey(0);
    //outputfile << dog[0] << endl;
    //cout << "M = " << endl << " " << dest[0] << endl << endl;
}
waitKey(0);
return 0;

}

   /**
* @function display_caption
*/
     int display_caption(const char* caption)
    {
        dst = Mat::zeros(src.size(), src.type());
        putText(dst, caption,
            Point(src.cols / 4, src.rows / 2),
            FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255));

        imshow(window_name, dst);
        int c = waitKey(DELAY_CAPTION);
        if (c >= 0) { return -1; }
        return 0;

    }


/**
* @function display_dst
*/
int display_dst(int delay)
{
    imshow(window_name, dst);
    int c = waitKey(delay);
    if (c >= 0) { return -1; }
    return 0;
}
```

Error is :***** VIDEOINPUT LIBRARY - 0.1995 - TFW07 *****

OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels)
, nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in cv::arithm_op, file C:\builds
lave64\win64_amdocl\master_PackSlave-win64-vc14-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\a
rithm.cpp, line 639
Press any key to continue . . .

PLease Help Thank you :)

Comment: which line is giving the error?

Comment: multipy function i think coz it says error in cv::arithm_op

Comment: Please reduce the code to the minimal example showing the problem. There's WAY too much code here. Also, check the call stack at the time of the error. It may be **detected** in `cv::arithm_op`, but it was **caused** somewhere else.

Comment: I'm pretty much sure it is multiply portion because when i commented that part ran  the  program it ran smoothly but i don;t know how to solve this problem :'(